# Error Method definition for 'uptimeMilliseconds' not found in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, xcode12

The error `Method definition for 'uptimeMilliseconds' not found` randomly showed up while I was programming with Swift on the newest Xcode Beta (Beta 4). I was working fine and compiling up to this point, but this error randomly occurred.
 I'm using Pods and this error showed up in `GoogleDataTransport`/`GDTCORClock` at `@implementation GDTCORClock`. 
Has someone experienced the same issue or does someone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: I added the "xcode12" tag, since this question is specific to the Xcode 12 beta build. (Unfortunately there is no "xcode12beta" tag).

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete code where you see this.  What you have right now is not enough information.

Comment: Solved: two Pods weren’t working with each other/ weren’t updated for Xcode12 beta

Comment: @gozzomain How did you determine the Pods weren't and weren't updated? Were you able to resolve this by updating the Pods? I am having the same error suddenly.

Comment: I remembered the last pod I added and removed that one. Pure luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing this same issue, even when trying to build in the newest non-beta version of Xcode.

I was able to solve it by doing the following:

- delete the Pods folder
- delete the *.xcworkspace file
- delete the Podfile.lock file
- run `pod install`